Web: Infinite Scrolling: Virtualization or not?
Is virtualization of infinite scroll for long lists on websites still necessary from a performance standpoint assuming clients use browsers on current mobile devices?
Is it dependent on the client-side framework (e.g. ReactJS vs VanillaJS)?
Did anyone do a recent benchmark/comparison?
Pros virtualization:

less DOM nodes:

less memory usage + possibly less images (but should be cached, if already loaded, anyways, so images use up memory)
less slowdown of browser: still true?



Cons virtualization:

browser native search does not work for non-rendered items
possible flicker, if scrolling fast
hard to get right for lists with items of different height

https://soundcloud.com seems to use no virtualization: browser native search works
https://open.spotify.com uses virtualization with placeholder items: ship their own search per list

see https://x.com/cramforce/status/1838573170728800386?t=PfEwSEd5QQVg7w_-lHh3nQ&s=08
